# Window.Print() is not working when built to iOS

Tags: ios, windows-phone-7, cordova, printing

I am fairly new to programming in PhoneGap, I have only been working on one project but I have been doing it for two months now. I am programming for Windows Phone and then building via PhoneGap's website. The problem I am running into is that i am using window.print() to print a couple of reports. It works fine in my browser and on Windows Phone. However, when I build to iOS, there is no print functionality at all. It seems to just skip that line of code and continue. Has anyone experienced this? Any help? We are trying to show this functionality at a trade show tomorrow, so immediate help is GREATLY needed. Thanks.

Comment: I must be missing something here: what do you mean with "works fine in my browser and on Windows Phone"? Have you tested the app in a real device? As far as I know, WP7 has no printing support...

Answer (score -2):

use `console.log()`  it works in all major platforms

Comment: But I need it to print a page, not log something. I know what console.log does and it is not what I am looking for. I need to print a page to a printer.

Comment: what do you mean ?! print a page from ios device ?!

Comment: Well, being a PhoneGap application, it is one large html page with a seperate div for each "page" of the application. I have a "page" that is a report that I need to print. To do this I have a print button that calls window.print(). It works great on my local machine, Windows Phone, and Android, but does nothing in iOS.